# Prisma & MongoDB query not working as intended

Tags: mongodb, next.js, where-clause, relationship, prisma

In the following Prisma query on MongoDB, when the `orderBy` clause is being added, the `where` clause is being ignored. Please help.

```
const unansweredQuestions = await prisma.question.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      entryDate: 'desc',
    },
    where: {
      NOT: {
        responses: {
          some: {
            userId,
          },
        },
      },
    },
   
    skip,
    take,
  });
```

The schema file is as following:

```
datasource db {
  provider     = "mongodb"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}


model User {
  id            String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  responses     Response[]
}

model Question {
  id          String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  question    String
  options     String[]
  answer      String
  explanation String
  subject     String
  tags        String[]
  newsDate    DateTime
  entryDate   DateTime
  responses   Response[]
}

model Response {
  id             String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user           User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId         String   @db.ObjectId
  question       Question @relation(fields: [questionId], references: [id])
  questionId     String   @db.ObjectId
  selectedOption String
  responseDate   DateTime
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your schema file as well so that I can replicate it locally and check?

Comment: @NurulSundarani Schema added

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try to reproduce it shortly. What response do you currently get?

Comment: When I use orderBy, the where clause is completely ignored.